# Laravel 7 Auto logout when session expired

Tags: laravel

I would like to logout the page and redirected to the login page when the session expires in Laravel 7. Can any one please help me to do this? Thank you

Comment: It already does that right? Do you mean you want to customize laravel's session timeout?

Comment: Take a look at [This](https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-logout-on-session-expire/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It is not logout automatically and when we click after session expiry then it triggers some error message by showing all the codes. I would like to avoid that scenario. That post also I already tried. When I add the code in Kernel, it is showing some error.

Comment: could you post the error as well?

Comment: "it triggers some error message by showing all the codes"; this sounds like you have your application in dev mode

Comment: It is confirmed that it is not in development mode. APP_ENV=production is there in .env. Already some codes are there under protected $middleware in kernel.php and when I add this code then it is showing that symbols like syntax error by underlines.

Answer (score 0):

There is normally this functionality implemented in Laravel. You need a POST request to the '/logout' route with (and therefore a csrf field in your request).

Usually you have in your blade a hidden form for that and a button or a link (it depends on what you use) that activates the sending of the form (with javascript).

For example, in the basic template of laravel we have this:

The form that is hidden:

```
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
  @csrf
</form>
```

The link used here to allow the user to log out:

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.querySelector('#logout-form').submit();">
```